# Cannot load a URDF file using pybullet

Tags: python, ros

i have designed and exported a URDF model of a robot using solidworks and the sw2urdf plugin. Now i am trying to load it using pybullet module in python to simulate it and i keep getting the error of:

error: Cannot load URDF file.

Any help would be much appreciated as this doesn't give much information about what might be wrong?

Comment: hey i havn't full figured it out yet but i believe it has something to do with setting coordinate system for each joint if that helps any also stuck, will keep posted

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the urdf file that you created has been connected to obj file. If you open ufdf file there must be a object link.
<mesh filename=""...>

Answer (score 0):

firstly you need to entire folder from the export in the directory you using. Secondly make sure all coordinate systems match for the global and each joint between links.

This seemed to work for me